# Fitting multiple Keras models consecutively leads to GPU OOM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to fit and save three models consecutively on the same data (the NIH-Chest set - https://www.nih.gov/news-events/news-releases/nih-clinical-center-provides-one-largest-publicly-available-chest-x-ray-datasets-scientific-community). Even though I can do this separately I am wondering if I can do this from a list (see code below). At this point however this leads to a GPU memory saturation and consequently an OOM error. This is caused by the dataset not being flushed from the GPU memory and trying to reload it as well for the second and third fit.

All the solutions relating clearing the GPU memory either involve closing Cuda or restarting Keras  or the kernel...which in causes fit to be erased (no surprise there).

I am wondering, is it possible to fit multiple models consecutively from a list or should I just go back to basics and fit and save every model separate?

Small code snippet (for a quick test run > small# epochs and validation);

```
epochs = 2
i = 0
for model in model_list:
    i += 1
    model.fit_generator(train_data, epochs = epochs, validation_data = validation_data, validation_steps = 100)
    model.save('model_{}'.format(i))
```

Comment: You can use `keras.backend.clear_session()` at the end of the for loop. This clears the model graph in the session. Alternatively, you can run `del(model)`  at the end of the loop to remove from memory

Comment: clear_session() leads to an new error; 'ValueError: Tensor("training/Adam/Const:0", shape=(), dtype=int64) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Adam_1/iterations:0", shape=(), dtype=resource).'  Which I thought was related to clearing the Keras session. The second suggestions appears to work, it seems I missed something while implementing this a few hours ago!

Comment: So, should I post it as an answer?

Comment: Ill leave the honors to you, it feels wrong to claim your answer:). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `del(model)` at the end of the loop. This would delete the memory of the model which you would not intend to use later.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this at the end of loop,

`K.clear_session()`

Note: to import it

```
from keras import backend as K
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue recently, in my case the other answers were missing a garbage collect call.

```
import gc
import tensorflow as tf

... 
for iModelParams in modelsParams:
  iModel = BuildModel(iModelParams)
  iModel.fit(...)
  del(model)
  gc.collect()
  tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```

Probably would be cleaner to just use with: but I haven't tried it out.